# How should "per" be written (as in, sales per country, sales/country, sales per/country)?

Tags: grammar

I have a co-worker who writes phrases like this:

> I need monthly sales per/country for all of 2023...

I'm very sure she's doing it wrong. I think it should be either:

> I need monthly sales per country for all of 2023...

...or:

> I need monthly sales/country for all of 2023...

...but not both. The way I see it, it's sales-over-country, the same way speed is distance-over-time.

Before I mention it to her (again, since I mentioned it a few years ago), I'd like to be a bit more sure. I've been embarrassed in the past when I assumed her double-spacing between sentences (which I had never seen before) was an accident, only to discover it was taught as the correct form a few decades ago.

So my question is, is "sales per/country" some archaic-but-still-valid form or is it just the weird mix that I think it is?

Comment: You are right. Your colleague's usage is off. The better one is using 'per' since '/' is also used to indicate an alternative.

Comment: The "/" in this context is an abbreviation for "per". So the example sentence would be read aloud: "I need monthly sales PER PER country for all of 2023."

Comment: @MetaEd Exactly my reasoning.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/per

Comment: @WeatherVane "sales/country" is unlikely to be misunerstood as alternatives, since there's no likely context where you're choosing between them. And in a financial context, it's obvious that it means "per", and this usage is extremely common.

Comment: @WeatherVane There is a use for using both "per" and the solidus. Consider the case of a company based in a state of a federation that sells primarily to other states but also sells to other countries. They may well require sales figures to be broken down as "sales per state/country". The use of both "per" **and** the solidus in the question thus becomes a source of confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(A) Is the co-worker right ?
No , it is redundant to user "per" & "/" at the same time.
Department of Redundancy Department will encourage the usage of such wrong & incorrect usages which is not right.

(B) Should you inform or rectify the co-worker , who did not listen the first time around ?
No , it is no big deal & the co-worker is not going to change.
You should just laugh it off & not use it yourself.

(C) Here is one example where you can see the 2 ways to write it out :

https://www.eia.gov/petroleum/gasdiesel/

> U.S. Regular Gasoline Prices (**dollars per gallon**)
> Regular Gasoline October 2023 Retail price: **$3.61/gallon**

(D) Here is one more example :

https://www.energysage.com/local-data/electricity-cost/

> The national average electricity rate is **23 cents per kilowatt-hour**
> Arkansas **13.26 ¢ / kWh**

(E) You can gently show more such online examples to your co-worker , without mentioning that "X per/ Y" is wrong & without expecting changes.

Comment: _"Should you inform or rectify the co-worker"_ She did listen; she just forgot. That was about 6 years ago, lol. However it's not just about correcting someone; she produces most of the marketing material on our website and I care greatly about our maintaining a certain level of quality. It reflects poorly on a company that primarily sells children's story books if the marketing material contains obvious grammatical errors.

Comment: Oh , when the Situation is not some casual internal emailing & not her Domain , then it is not worthwhile & should be handled gently ! When you inform us that the Situation is actually her Domain , @Clonkex , then that is a serious glaring issue & should be rectified forthwith !